# Impossible to invoke a method ("getUrl") on a string variable ("60")

Tags: assets, entry-type

I'm a beginner and don't understand this error, and how to correct it:

**Template error**
Impossible to invoke a method ("getUrl") on a string variable ("60")

I'm trying to display only the first entry of one loop. In my case,
'*selectedArtwork*' has an *Entries* type and '*pictures*' an *Assets* type.

Here is my code:

```
{% if entry.selectedArtwork | length %}
    {% for artwork in entry.selectedArtwork %}

        {% set assets = artwork.pictures.first() %}
        {% if assets | length %}
            {% for asset in assets %}

                {% set artworkPicture = { width: 475 } %}
                {% set artworkPictureRetina = { width: 930 } %}

                <figure>
                    <img data-interchange="[{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}, (default)], [{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPictureRetina) }}, (retina)]" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">

                    <noscript>
                        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">
                    </noscript>
                </figure>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And the part of code highlighted in Craft's debug mode are:

```
<img data-interchange="[{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}, (default)], [{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPictureRetina) }}, (retina)]" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">

<noscript>
    <img src="{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">
</noscript>
```

This code is working well as an entry template of another page of my website to display all entries, but not here for my homepage to only display the first entry.

Comment: Can you clarify what type of fields are 'selectedArtwork' and 'pictures'?  A Matrix and Assets field, respectively?

Comment: 'selectedArtwork' = Entries and 'pictures' = Assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is here:

```
{% set assets = artwork.pictures.first() %}
{% if assets | length %}
  {% for asset in assets %}
```

This sets `assets` to the first `artwork.pictures`, not to a list of assets, and then you try to loop over that single asset.

If you want a `figure` for every `pictures` of every `selectedArtwork` of your entry, try this:

```
{% set artworkPicture = { width: 475 } %}
{% set artworkPictureRetina = { width: 930 } %}

{% for artwork in entry.selectedArtwork %}
  {% for asset in artwork.pictures %}
    <figure>
      <img data-interchange="[{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}, (default)], [{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPictureRetina) }}, (retina)]" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">
      <noscript>
        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">
      </noscript>
    </figure>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

- set `artworkPicture` and `artworkPictureRetina` once, outside your loop.
- no need to use `{% if ...|length %}`. If the length is 0, the for loop will run 0 times.

If you want a `figure` for the first `picture` of every `selectedArtwork`, try this:

```
{% set artworkPicture = { width: 475 } %}
{% set artworkPictureRetina = { width: 930 } %}

{% for artwork in entry.selectedArtwork %}
  {% set asset = artwork.pictures.first %}
  {% if asset %}
    <figure>
      <img data-interchange="[{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}, (default)], [{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPictureRetina) }}, (retina)]" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">
      <noscript>
        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">
      </noscript>
    </figure>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want a `figure` for the first `picture` of the first `selectedArtwork`, try this:

```
{% set artworkPicture = { width: 475 } %}
{% set artworkPictureRetina = { width: 930 } %}

{% set artwork = entry.selectedArtwork.first %}
{% if artwork %}
  {% set asset = artwork.pictures.first %}
  {% if asset %}
    <figure>
      <img data-interchange="[{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}, (default)], [{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPictureRetina) }}, (retina)]" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">
      <noscript>
        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl(artworkPicture) }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth(artworkPicture) }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight(artworkPicture) }}">
      </noscript>
    </figure>
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I'm sorry, my question was not precise enough: I was trying to display only the first 'artwork' entry of the 'entry.selectedArtwork' loop.

Comment: Added that solution as well.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the template error but strangely it now outputs two pictures instead of only one... Any idea?

Comment: 2 entries in selectedArtwork?

Comment: Yes, in selectedArtwork.

Comment: So what you want is the first `pictures` of the first `selectedArtwork`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Sorry for not being specific enough. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I finally found how to:

{% for artwork in entry.selectedArtwork.limit(1).find() %}
{% set asset = artwork.pictures.first %}

So I added .limit(1).find() to output only one entry of the loop (in this case, the first), and then select only the first asset.

Thanks for your help :-)